# Select range in excel and making it a table for further reference

Tags: excel, select, range, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA coding. I am coding a piece for a specific dataset that is received once a quarter. I want the code to select the range and then make it a table after which columns will be added to the table etc.

I wrote the below code, however, it seems to do everything it should, but still gives me an error of "Type mismatch" but the actions still performs as it should.

Please advise on what causes the error (Error on line 20 - last step of selecting and creating table)

```
Sub QMRQOC()
'CREDIT MACRO
'Set Variables

Dim CrData As Worksheet
Set CrData = Worksheets("Credit Data")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Set StartCell = Range("A1")
Dim CrRng As Range
Dim CrTbl As ListObject


'Find last row and column
LastRow = CrData.Cells(CrData.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = CrData.Cells(StartCell.Row, CrData.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Select Range & make it a table
CrData.ListObjects.Add.Range(StartCell, CrData.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Name = "CrTbl"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your line of:

```
CrData.ListObjects.Add.Range(StartCell, CrData.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Name = "CrTbl"
```

to:

```
CrData.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(StartCell, CrData.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))).Name = "CrTbl"
```